# Apple fullscreen hook for Java

Tags: java, macos, swing

So far I have taking the application to fullscreen working without a problem.

However, when the user uses the operating system controls to bring the window out of fullscreen, I need to perform an action. Is there a hook or event that I can use to do this?

I found AppEventListener in com.apple.eawt, but it appears to be empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what's wrong with the `com.apple.eawt.FullScreenListener`

```
com.apple.eawt.FullScreenUtilities.addFullScreenListenerTo(window, new FullScreenListener() {

    @Override
    public void windowEnteringFullScreen(AppEvent.FullScreenEvent fse) {
    }

    @Override
    public void windowEnteredFullScreen(AppEvent.FullScreenEvent fse) {
    }

    @Override
    public void windowExitingFullScreen(AppEvent.FullScreenEvent fse) {
    }

    @Override
    public void windowExitedFullScreen(AppEvent.FullScreenEvent fse) {
    }
});
```

I simple inspection of the available methods in `FullScreenUtilities` in an IDE should have provided you with the required parameters for the method

Comment: +1 Thanks. Seemed to have overlooked this. Implemented it and working perfectly :)

Comment: @user278 Glad it worked, got to admit, the documentation is non-existant ;)